# How to do fill missing values in a column which are relative to another column?

Tags: r, missing-data

My data set has columns labelled "City", "Zipcode", "Neighbourhood". 
I have all the values for Neighbourhood but some values for city and zipcode are missing. How do I match the "Neighbourhood" columns to the given values in "City" and "Zipcode" and use it to fill the missing values of "City" and "Zipcode"?

Comment: [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on making an R question that folks can help with. That includes a sample of data, all necessary code, and a clear explanation of what you're trying to do and what hasn't worked.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a table with your complete cases, then replace the incomplete rows in your data from this:

```
complete.data <- unique(na.omit(data.df))
for (i in 1:nrow(data.df)){
  data.df[i,] <- complete.data[complete.data$Neighborhood %in% data.df$Neighborhood[i],]
}
```